# Validation error messages outside yield

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

To display validation errors in the view, I seem to need access to the instance variable. [From the Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views):

```
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
```

I want to output the error messages outside the `yield` area, is it still possible to access the object's error messages?

Comment: Yes, it's possible (`@post` variable 'lives' in entire template).

Comment: Maybe I was a little bit vague. I'd like to be able to display errors for multiple models/controllers, e.g. `@post`, `@user`, `@category` etc... So I guess I'd need to catch instance variables that has error messsages without beforehand knowing their existence/wording.