# Possible to identify instance variables if we don't know about their existence beforehand?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an instance variable set in the controller with a certain attribute, e.g.

```
@post.errors
```

Is there any method to check in the view *without knowing* about `@post` (or any other instance variable):

a) Is there any instance variable available?
b) If the above is true, does it have the attribute `errors` set?

**Update**

If the above questions are returning true, then return the instance variable.

Comment: I want to confirm existence of `@post` (or any other possible instance variable). But not in the controller - in the view. To clarify: the view will not know about any instance variable at all, so it wants to check - "Is there any instance variables available at all?"

Comment: The nature of this question leads me to ask: what is the problem you are actually trying to solve? Do you want to reuse the same view for different controllers, where different instance variables will be set? If so, or something like it, then there is a better solution than solving the immediate technical problem presented here.

Comment: @Confusion: Agreed. For example raising exceptions is usually a better mechanism than setting error flags and then needing to search for and check them.

Comment: I have a problem in a Rails app where I need to render validation error messages in a place in the templates where it would be cumbersome to statically register all possible instance variable. I created a question about that specific problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778275/validation-error-messages-outside-yield But I wanted to learn the more general view on this problem, hence the question on this page.

Comment: If you want to reuse the same view for multiple controllers, you can e.g. pass the currently relevant entity (`@post` or `@user` or ...) as a 'local' variable using `render 'template', locals: {instance: @post}` in one controller and `render 'template', locals: {instance: @user}` in another. You can then access that entity as 'instance' in your template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be one way to check if any instance variable in the current scope has a `true` value for `errors`

```
error_somewhere = instance_variables.any? do |var_symbol|
  var_value = instance_variable_get( var_symbol )
  var_value.respond_to?( :errors ) ? var_value.errors : false
end
```

You may need to modify the third line depending on what data you are expecting from the `errors` method in general (not clear from your question).

You may also want to modify this further to identify the error-ing variable (you could use a `map` and a `compact` or perhaps write to a hash)

For example, the following will construct a hash of variable names and their values, but only populated with instance variables that have an `errors` method that returns a true value:

```
these_have_errors = Hash[ 
  instance_variables.map do |var_symbol|
    var_value = instance_variable_get( var_symbol )
    if var_value.respond_to?( :errors ) && var_value.errors
     [ var_symbol, var_value ]
    else
     nil
    end
  end.compact
]
```

If run inside your controller, or if you add `controller.` before the `instance_variables*` methods, you should get a result like:

```
{ :@post => (value of @post) }
```

when @post exists and has a true return value from `@post.errors`.

The important methods here that give you the introspection to do the task:

- [instance_variables](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables)
- [instance_variable_get](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get)
- [respond_to?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-respond_to-3F)

Comment: Great! But how would I return the object so I can work with the instance variable, instead of only `true`?

Answer (score 1):

In your view, you can do

```
controller.instance_variables
```

This will return an Array of all the instance varibles of you controller class.

Please note that this will include variables that Rails has initialized like

`:@_routes, :@_action_has_layout, :@_headers`, along with what you have initialized in your `action`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [try object](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)

```
@post.try(:errors)
```